# Is that possible to use query plan for dynamic SOQL queries?

Tags: dynamic-soql, performance

I know we can verify straightforward SOQL in query plan. Now, I am trying to find a way to use query planner for a dynamic SOQL queries. My SOQL query depends on several Ids (list of Ids) and binding variables which will be available only in the run time. Now, is that possible to verify a complex dynamic query in query planner? Please provide some guidance.

Comment: Yes, just make sure to use typical inputs or better still check the plan for each of the input patterns.